# Create DEM from cartosat stereo pairs?

Tags: dem, remote-sensing, photogrammetry, osgeo4w

I have two carstosat stereo pair images. All i need to do is to extract DEM from those.
So, i tried it doing with OSGeo4W. but i didn't succeeded in it.

So IS there any other softwares or opensource for extracting DEM from cartosat pair?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several softwares for doing this. Here is a non exhaustive list :

Commercial licence :

- [Imagine Photogrammetry  (= formerly LPS)](http://geospatial.intergraph.com/products/imagine-photogrammetry/Details.aspx)  This is very powerful but very expensive
- [ENVI DEM module](http://www.exelisvis.com/docs/IntroductionToDEMExtraction.html)
- [photoscan](http://www.agisoft.ru/products/photoscan) Not very expensive, but more oriented toward drone image processing, so not the best for satellite data

Open source :

- [Orfeo Toolbox](http://orfeo-toolbox.org/CookBook/CookBookse13.html#x61-1130003.6) Not tested for photogrammetry, but the modules are there
- [MicMac](http://publiclab.org/notes/mathew/7-12-2012/micmac-another-os-photogrammetry-program) I've heard of it but never tested. Again, this is more for drone data and not really for satellite data. And not very easy to manipulate...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and i would like to ask that is there any other open source rather than [Orfeo Toolbox](http://orfeo-toolbox.org/CookBook/CookBookse13.html#x61-1130003.6)? and i will look in to this commercial softwares if i have to.  I am using this [Orfeo Toolbox](http://orfeo-toolbox.org/CookBook/CookBookse13.html#x61-1130003.6) but iam facing errors for the data i have. iam working on that.

Comment: I've added one more. Otherwise there are of course other OS remote sensing software (BEAM, GRASS) but they do not have photogrammetry module from what I know.

Comment: @ radouxju I had a doubt that do the Images need to be orthorectified before doing the Dem extraction?

Comment: @Sandy For the creation of a DEM (in fact a DSM, digital surface model) with a stereo pair, you need to have the original images in the sensor geometry. You then create an epipolar pair of image based on the geometry of acquisition (at this stage, you can visualize your data in 3D), then you extract the DEM (your software has to find homologous points based on some correlation tools). It is only after those steps that you can create a true orthorectified image. If the 2 images of your stereo pair are already orthorectified, you cannot extract a DEM.

Comment: @radouxju from the pair of images i have how do i know they are orthorectified?

Comment: there are two Cartosat products : standard and ortho kit. standard is geometrically processed (in other words, approximatively orthorectified). Ortho kit is provided with RPC files to help you do the orthorectification and DEM extraction by yourself. The metadata should tell you if you have standard or ortho kit product.

Comment: @radouxju Thank you.. yeah i had orthokit imagery (i had RPC files and i had looked in metadata) So i can extract DEM from these stereo pair, but when i am using the Orfeo Toolbox i am unable to extract the DEM. whether OTB is used for specific imagery? or can we do it with cartosat also?